# notes.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, filter

Trying to some filtered notes with the renderedNotes function but got an error  Object doesn't support property or method 'filter

Have gone through the code and even this documentation to see if there is any violations but found none https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
let renderedNotes = function(notes, filters){
    let filteredNotes = notes.filter(function(note){
        return note.title.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase())
        })
        document.querySelector('.notes').innerHTML = ''
        filteredNotes.forEach(function(note){
        document.querySelector('.notes').appendChild(generateDom(note));
    })
}
```

I expect the error to go away and i get the notes rendered in the browser

Comment: where's the `notes` data ?

Comment: Can you plz share the data on which you are trying to filter